# Wordpress CSS Navigation Menu Hover Fade Effect

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, hover, fadein

My wordpress website navigation menu pops up a sub-menu directly , can you help me with it's CSS to pop it up smoothly and fade in the sub-menus on

like this example :

http://jsfiddle.net/ChH4F/1/

i tried it on wordpress but it didn't work

I tried this and didn't work

```
 .main-navigation ul li ul.sub-menu 
{
 transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
.main-navigation  ul.sub-menu:hover
{
 opacity: 1;
    height: auto;
    overflow: none;
}
```

here's my css for the wordpress menu-navigation

{

```
.main-navigation {
    margin-top: 24px;
    margin-top: 1.714285714rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.main-navigation li {
    margin-top: 24px;
    margin-top: 1.714285714rem;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-size: 0.857142857rem;
    line-height: 1.42857143;

}
.main-navigation a {
    color: #5e5e5e;
}


.main-navigation a:hover {
    color: #21759b;
}

.main-navigation ul.nav-menu,
.main-navigation div.nav-menu > ul {
   display: none;

}
.main-navigation ul.nav-menu.toggled-on,
.menu-toggle {
    display: inline-block;

}
</i>
```

Comment: animation effect works for me in chrome on a mac

Comment: Any reason for the `</i>` at the end of your css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're styling two different elements

".main-navigation ul li ul.sub-menu" is not equal to ".main-navigation ul.sub-menu:hover"

When you fix this bug, if it doesn't work try to use "ease-in-out" instead of "ease"

:)